# Unable to place <div> properly

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a divisions like this:

[Layout http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5742/nf5l.png](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5742/nf5l.png)

The top three works good, it's just the footer one which is creating the problem.

```
#banner
    {
    background: url(image.gif) repeat-x;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:340px;
    }
.container
    {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:960px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#000;
    }

.left-container 
    {
    width:55.72916%;
    float:left;
    }
.right-container    
    {
    text-align:center;
    width:44%;
    float:right;
    padding-top:25px;
    }
```

banner refers to the first div in black..

Now how should I style the footer div, because when I am putting some info, it's appearing just below banner div and overlapping with left and right container.

And...

whenever I am using `<p>` tag and specifying some font-size, why is it automatically taking margin-top and bottom equal to font-size.. is it its property?

Comment: Please post your HTML markup as well.

Comment: Did you try `clear:both` on the footer div??

Comment: The answer to the last question is yes: paragraphs have top and bottom margins of `1em`, the same as the font size. You can easily change that to something in pixels though.

Answer (score 0):

YOur question is not complete but looks like you need `clear:both` on your footer element.

Answer (score 0):

first of all question is not clear here,

**to avoid `overlapping with left and right container.`**(i guess green boxes refer these)

if u want to make the footer rectangle appear like header(i guess black box).u may need to use `overflow:hidden;` in both green rectangle or `clear:both;` on the footer div

**to avoid `it's appearing just below banner div`**(i guess banner means the black box)

use `margin-top:50px;`(for example) in footer to make distance from header